# How to predict the value of VLOOKUP in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am having this table:

[image]

In the cell containing David, I used the formula =VLOOKUP(33,B3:D11,3,TRUE). Can somebody explain me why it returns David?

Comment: Use False instead of True (you have to sort by column B ascending if you use True) in your formula and if you want James change 2 to 3 (vlookup start columns from B is 1, C is 2, D is 3)

Answer (score 2):

The data and formula you presented return Bricklayer (not David).

Working through the formula parameters:

33 : this exists in the list in row 10, but your final parameter TRUE means that Excel will return an approximate match. So Excel goes through the first few rows, sees 32 in row 7, and 35 in row 8, and figures 33 was skipped and that row 7 is the closest

B3:D11 : looks like the correct range

2 : returns data from the second column in the provided range (column C), i.e. Bricklayer

TRUE : as mentioned above, tells Excel to use approximate matching. If you used FALSE, the function would return Zoo Owner. Personally, I always use FALSE to prevent odd results

Comment: Can you please clarify your explanation for the return value in this case?

Comment: Sorry but I erroneously wrote 2 instead of 3 (for the range_lookup) in this worksheet. I corrected the code anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Using  `TRUE` as last parameters returns an approximate match, and it also supposes that your data is sorted by first column, which is not the case.

Use `FALSE` as last parameter.

This is the first common problem listed for `VLOOKUP` in [office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1):

> If range_lookup is TRUE or left out, the first column needs to be sorted alphabetically or numerically. If the first column isn't sorted, the return value might be something you don't expect. Either sort the first column, or use FALSE for an exact match.

Comment: My question is: if I use TRUE, how do I figure out the result?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If your source data is sorted then you get the correct result with  `true` add last parameter.  Otherwise you shouldn't use `true` and don't rely on the result.